# como ejecuto schedule:run de manera local?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Estoy trabajando con Tareas Programadas en mi proyecto Laravel. Ya cree un command para la tarea, me funciona bien, el problema radica cuando quiero que se ejecute cada vez que yo le mande. Por ejemplo, lo tengo que se ejecute cada minuto.

Ya ejecute schedule:run, sé que debo hacer un  job para que me lo ejecute de manera local, cada vez que lo mande.
lo que no sé es como hacerlo de manera local.

Encontre que en linux es de esta forma: * * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Quisiera saber como hago en Windows?

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{

```
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\EstadoDeInspeccion',
];


protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('command:name')->everyMinute();
   
}


protected function commands()
{
    $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

    require base_path('routes/console.php');
}
```

}

Comment: Solo se me esta ejecutando una sola vez, cuando corro el comando

Comment: Tienes que hacer un cronjob que ejecute el comando. No conozco de windows, pero revisa las [publicaciones de stackoverflow](https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-unknown&biw=360&bih=512&sxsrf=ALeKk02VGKPltVjknfUnVofLRX25NCgV8Q%3A1595527845658&ei=pdIZX9DfJ6uf5OUPk7ejoAM&q=cron+job+windows+site%3Aes.stackoverflow.com&oq=cron+job+windows+site%3Aes.stackoverflow.com&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAM6BAgAEEdQ_iRY8TdghzxoAHABeACAAeIBiAHzBJIBBTAuMS4ymAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp) que seguramente encontrarás como hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

Según las documentación de Laravel la manera de correr un Taskjob es en una consola que se encuentre en la raiz del proyecto y correr el siguiente comando

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

eso iniciara el servicio de manera local, lo que encontraste para linux es una configuración que puedes colocar en el servidor para que corra ese comando cada cierto tiempo el cual es determinado por la cantidad de " * ".

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Suerte.

Comment: Gracias Amgios, ya encontre la manera de hacerlo en windows. Toca hacerlo por el programador de tareas